# Prove, that equation xaxba=xbc has only one solution, for firmly selected a,b,c, from group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have to prove this theorem: elements $a,b,c$ are firmly selected elements of a group. Prove that equation 
$$
xaxba = xbc
$$

has only one solution.

I have no idea how to prove this statement.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$axba=bc$$ or
$$xba=a^{-1}bc$$ or
$$x=a^{-1}bc(ba)^{-1}$$ and since $a^{-1}bc(ba)^{-1}$ is an unique, for which it's true, we are done!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What happens if you apply the inverse of $(xa)$ to the left of both sides of the equality and then the inverse of $(bc)$ to the right of both sides of you equality?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the equation $xaxba=xbc$ we can multiply it by $x^{-1}$ from the left to get$$x^{-1}xaxba = x^{-1}xbc\\
axba=bc$$

Now, multiply the equation by $a^{-1}$ from the left and you get

$$a^{-1}axba = a^{-1}bc\\
xba = a^{-1}bc$$

Now, try to multiply the equation with some element from the right, and continue doing so until you get $x=something$.